# How do I use screen sharing in Ubuntu GNOME?

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, ubuntu-gnome

In Ubuntu GNOME, there is a section in the Settings called *Sharing*. I enabled screen sharing and it gives me an address like `vnc://you-computer-here.local`. How can I  connect to it?

Comment: You may find this useful: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To connect to your VNC server, I recommend you use `remmina`.

If it is not installed by default, you can install it, by typing the following in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install remmina
```

However, if you want to do remote admin work, it's a good practice to use the command line and `ssh`.